# For Loop, while Limit is a Negative Number

Tags: javascript, html

I am relatively new to programming and I am taking a Web programming course in my University studies. Using JavaScript, we are to write a for loop that, will compute the total of all integers from 0 up to, and including, the limit.

I was able to get all integers from 0 and above to successfully work, however, when I enter a negative integer (-3 for instance) the function does not return a total of 0 as it should. I simply returns nothing at all. I will include my JavaScript code below. If anyone has some tips to help out, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function () {
    var limit = document.getElementById('limit').value;
    var total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= limit; i ++) {
        total = total + i;
        document.getElementById('total').value = total;
    };
};
```

Comment: Move `document.getElementById('total').value = total;` after `for`-loop's end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output, `document.getElementById('total').value = total;` is **inside** loop.

Move it **outside** of loop or it won't be executed (and nothing will show up)

*Loop* is executed 0 times, so this line *in this loop* is executed 0 times too.

Comment: What is the problem of having this line inside the `for` loop - why wouldn't it be executed?

Comment: Loop is executed 0 times, so this line in a loop is executed 0 times too.

Comment: Yes, however, this explanation belongs in the answer. OP obviously doesn't know it, else he would have spotted the problem. Simply stating "don't do that" without explaining the reasoning will not make him aware of _why_ that should be.

Comment: @vlaz, tnx, moved inside.

Comment: Yes, I was unaware. I have only been working in JavaScript for about 2 weeks now. I appreciate the help! @Dimava

Answer (score 0):

your setting the value inside the for loop just move `document.getElementById('total').value = total;`

to the bottom, outside the for loop that way it will always render total even if its 0 due to negative number.

```
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function () {

var limit = document.getElementById('limit').value;

var total = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= limit; i ++) {

    total = total + i;



};
document.getElementById('total').value = total;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must move the last line, where the value is assigned to the element with id `total`, outside the for loop. If the limit is less than 0, then the code inside the loop will never be executed.

Try running the code snippet below:

```js
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() {

  var limit = document.getElementById('limit').value;

  var total = 0;

  for (i = 0; i <= limit; i++) {
    total = total + i;
  }

  document.getElementById('total').value = total;
};
```

```html
Limit: <input id="limit" type="number" value="3" /><br />
<input id="total" type="text" />
<button id="go">Go</button>
```